# Package gtk-sharp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

I tried to run `mcs hello.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0`
on ubuntu but it showed this error:

```
Package gtk-sharp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk-sharp-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk-sharp-2.0' found
error CS8027: Error running pkg-config. Check the above output.
```

I'm new to this, what should I do?

Comment: Do search to find gtk-sharp-2.0.pc.  Then add -LIB option to mcs command line.  See : https://www.mankier.com/1/mcs